# Smoke flow object color property is behaving oddly and changing color

Tags: smoke-simulation, mantaflow

I have two flow objects in one domain... one is green the other blue but both are color-shifting. The green one starts with a puff of green but the overall smoke comes out blue. The blue one does it too but less. It goes from the selected blue colour to a pale, desaturated blue.

I've corrected the colour below in the shader with the Hue saturation node but I'd rather have reliable color coming out of the flow object.

The only value changed in the flow object's properties was the colour.

[image: ViewPort]

Comment: Additional playing has revealed that this has something to do with the noise on the domain. I set up a new quick smoke to test and the color was fine until toggling noise.

Any reason that the noise should interact with the color? Any way to make it not without losing the noise?

Comment: Hello, could you add these additional informations + screenshots illustrating this in the question ? As this stands it's a little hard to understand. Have you tried lighting your smoke with a stronger light ?

Comment: I appreciate you taking a look but it looks like I've identified the issue. A coloured smoke flow object will colour-shift if you toggle the Noise in its Domain.  You can see the result in the above image. I've tested this with several different simulations now.